# Delay in sending emails while using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, phpmailer, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send email in my express powered app. But the emails gets delivered with the delay of 4 minutes. However If I send the same email using same mail server But using php instead of node it get delivered instantly.

I came from PHP background and that's why I am tested it with PHP. I think I am using a dumb nodejs package to send the mail. In php I mostly use PHPmailer. Is there any good nodejs library to send email easily.

Comment: *Is there any good nodejs library to send email easily* - there is. It's Nodemailer. There are no good reasons why Nodemailer works with a delay while another mailer doesn't. The problem is specific to your mail server or other factors that weren't listed in the question. If you can make the problem reproducible for other users with other mail servers (preferably local), consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and opening an issue in Nodemailer repo. You can try to debug the server with https://nodemailer.com/smtp/dsn/

Comment: Well I am using the same mail server with same connection configuration and even sending the same email to same user. But I know still there must be other factors causing the issue. If you can suggest some of these other factors that could help me finding the problem

Comment: If you have a delay in your app somewhere, that's what would cause a delay. Don't use Express. Try to use Nodemailer directly. And debug delivery status with DSN if possible.

Comment: No delay is not due to express app. I am saying that because when mail arrives after 4 minutes. the time of arrival of email is displayed as 4 minutes ago. that means the inbox provider knows that the email is send 4 minutes ago.

Comment: Then mail server needs to be debugged. I'd expect that the problem is with this specific mail server. You won't know that for sure without trying it with other mail servers. I'm not aware of any possible differences between libs that would cause that. This still may depend on the way you use Nodemailer. The question doesn't contain MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

This is really too broad a question for SO. PHPMailer and nodemailer are very similar in how they work, so it would help to show any differences in configuration between the two (e.g. are they using the same mail server?).

You need to figure out the difference in routing between the two - that's pretty much the only thing that could account for such a large delay. For best performance, you should be sending through a local mail server, and you'll be able to inspect its logs to see where the time is going.

Comment: yes I am using same mail server with same configurations

Comment: So look at the differences in what is logged in each case, or use a profiler